# Migration issue while modifying the column of table in laravel

Tags: laravel

**For modifying a column length and type I have run the following commands**

My column name is `course_slot_id` have `int(11)` and I want to change it `varchar(100)`

```
- composer require doctrine/dbal
- php artisan make:migration modify_course_slot_id_table --table=course_booking
- php artisan migrate
```

**My Migration**

```
class ModifyCourseSlotIdTable extends Migration 
{ 
    public function up()
    { 
        Schema::table('course_booking', function (Blueprint $table) { 
            $table->string('course_slot_id', 100)->nullable()->change(); 
        }); 
    } 

    public function down()
    { 
        Schema::table('course_booking', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //...
        }); 
    } 
}
```

**When I run the migrate command I got the following issue**

```
In AbstractPlatform.php line 434:
Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.
```

Comment: Add your `modify_course_slot_id_table` migration file also

Comment: Looks similar to this: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3161

Comment: @bhavinjr following is the modify_course_slot_id_table codes

Comment: class ModifyCourseSlotIdTable extends Migration
{
   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('course_booking', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('course_slot_id', 100)->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('course_booking', function (Blueprint $table) {
          
        });
    }
}

Comment: @cbaconnier Can you please explain the process ?